# Severe backup failure

Tags: upgrade, backup, encryption

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04.05 LTS. Before doing so I made a backup of all of my files. However, the upgrade did not work. Every time I signed in I was redirected to the log in. So I erased my harddisk and played Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS on it. It works pretty well, but I cannot access my files anymore! Every time I type in my password for my backup disc I get the following message:

Error unlocking /dev/sdb2: Error spawning command-line `cryptsetup luksOpen "/dev/sdb2" "luks-0b7f3b35-5d0f-4980-86ed-d93c8951e894" ': Failed to execute child process "cryptsetup" (No such file or directory) (g-exec-error-quark, 8)

Answer (score 3):

From https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515890 which has identical symptoms indicates that you need to install cryptsetup.

```
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup
```

Comment: I have access to my files, however, I cannot unpack them with the software on Ubuntu MATE. Everytime I try to unpack them I get a failure report.

Comment: The report says that unpacking the files failed due to an "unknown failure". Part of the protocol states